# Ответ Дан в мобильной версии сайта

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В мобильной версии сайта при указании времени публикации ответа указано:

> Ответ Дан

[image: ответ дан]

Нужно исправить на:

> Ответ дан

Comment: Вимм Билль Данн

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Жан Клон Ван Ответ Дан

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, на какой именно странице вы видите эту строку?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky на любой, где есть ответ.

Comment: Проблема была не в переводе, а в css-стилях. Как я понимаю, поправили. С ближайшим обновлением, должно появиться на сайте.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а кто поправил? Создавался ли для этого какой-то общедоступный баг-репорт или это уже внутренняя кухня SO?

Comment: Этот пост и есть описание дефекта. Далее я попросил конкретного человека исправить дефект. Поскольку изменения тривиальны, все уложилось в одну просьбу в чате.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а Вы можете этому конкретному человеку рассказать о другой [похожей ситуации](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300894/339911)?

Comment: @alexolut Отписался «конкретному» человеку!