# Описание Привилегий

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В описании всех [привилегий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), например, ["Доступ к аналитике сайта"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics), довольно странное форматирование слов - Каждое Слово Начинается С Большой Буквы:

> [image: Большие Буковки]

В transifex с этими строками не очень понятно. Чего-то нет, что-то есть, но без больших букв. Очень похоже, что проблема связана с другим, ранее найденным, [багом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3708/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0).

Comment: Это Стандарт Англоязычных Заголовков, у нас так не принято.