# Отображение срока пребывания на сайте

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Несмотря на обновленный уже как несколько дней [перевод](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/41580094?key=930bf60fabb24d48556af3936c0aa41d) строк, до сих пор надпись отображается с маленькой буквы:

[image: на сайте дней подряд]

Снова что-то со стилями как [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3897/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B9) и [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3708/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0)?

**UPD**

Проблема со строчной буквой (само?) устранилась. Но остался лишний пробел в начале строки. Это заметно при наведении мышки и появления подчеркивания:

[image: Пробел в начале строки]